# Running method on two variables at once

Tags: ruby

I am wondering what the proper way is to refactor this code for efficiency besides running it twice.

```html
class Hamming
  def compute (a, b)

    a.to_a.split("")
    b.to_a.split("")

  end
end
```

Is there something similar to assigning two variables at once like
`a, b = 1, 2`?

Comment: That code doesn't make sense. `split` works on strings, not arrays and it doesn't do anything with the result. When you say "efficiency" are you asking how do you not repeat yourself?

Comment: Yes. I meant to ask how to avoid repeating myself. I didn't even think to realize that you can't perform split on an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code doesn't make sense, I think what you're asking is how do you avoid repeating yourself.

Simple, write another method and call that. Here's an example of wanting to find out which phrase is longer, but you want to ignore lots of whitespace. So `foo          bar` isn't longer than `12345678`.

```
def longer_phrase(phraseA, phraseB)
    normalizedA = normalize(phraseA)
    normalizedB = normalize(phraseB)

    return normalizedA.length > normalizedB.length ? phraseA : phraseB
end

def normalize(phrase)
    normalized = phrase.gsub(/\s+/, ' ');
    normalized.strip!

    return normalized
end

puts longer_phrase("foo          bar  ", "12345678")
```

Needing to normalize all your data before doing work on it comes up a lot. This avoids repeating yourself. It makes your code easier to understand, since we know what the point of all that work is, to normalize the string. And it gives you a normalization function to use elsewhere so you're normalizing your data the same way.

Answer (score 2):

First off, your code is invalid. `#to_a` returns an array; `#split` is not defined on arrays.

Secondly, if your code *was* valid (say, `a.to_s.split(""); b.to_s.split("")`, it would not actually *do* much, because your code would just return the value of the last executed statement (`b.to_s.split("")`). Both `#to_s` and `#split` are non-destructive, which means they will not change `a` or `b` - the only effect you get from this function is what it returns, and you do not return the result of `a.to_s.split("")` in any way: it is forgotten.

If you meant something like this:

```
class Hamming
  def compute(a, b)
    [
      a.to_s.split(""),
      b.to_s.split("")
    ]
  end
end
```

this is fairly readable. However, if you had more complex operation than just `.to_s.split("")`, it would be better to isolate it into its own function:

```
class Hamming
  def compute(a, b)
    [
      list_chars(a),
      list_chars(b)
    ]
  end
  private def list_chars(str)
    str.to_s.split("")
  end
end
```

You could simplify it even more using `map`, but it really only becomes necessary when you have multiple elements, as the two-element case is perfectly legible as-is. However, here goes:

```
class Hamming
  def compute(a, b)
    [a, b].map { |x| list_chars(x) }
  end
  private def list_chars(str)
    str.to_s.split("")
  end
end
```

Also, you might want to see the method `#each_char`, giving you an iterator, which is more readable, and often the more correct choice, than `.split("")`.

EDIT: After thinking about it a bit, it seems like you're starting a method to evaluate a Hamming distance between two strings; and that you do not intend to have that function simply return the character of the two strings. In that case, I'd just write this:

```
def compute(a, b)
  a_chars = a.to_s.each_char
  b_chars = b.to_s.each_char
  # ...
end
```

or possibly this, if you absolutely need to have characters themselves, and not an iterator:

```
def compute(a, b)
  a_chars = a.to_s.each_char.to_a
  b_chars = b.to_s.each_char.to_a
  # ...
end
```

The solution I believe you are looking for would look like this:

```
def compute(a, b)
  a_chars, b_chars = *[a, b].map { |x| x.to_s.each_char.to_a }
  # ...
end
```

but I'd consider that less readable than the non-DRY one; if you really want to DRY it up, extract the listification into its own function as described above, and just do

```
a_chars = list_chars(a)
b_chars = list_chars(b)
```

which is actually the best of both worlds, even if it is a bit of an overkill in this case: it is DRY-ly maintainable and self-documentingly legible, for a bit of tradeoff in verbosity.